# Divide 24 hours in time intervals of 30 minutes

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am wondering how I would loop through a date/time or any type of variable to go from 00:00 to 24:00 every 30 Mins?

So I need a variable that shows times in 24HR format (01:00, 09:00) and every time I loop through it, to add 30 mins to the time? I then need to use this value in a string.

The time needs to start at 00:00AM and will end with 24:00.

Any ideas how should I go with it?

```
output should be like this - 00:00 00:30 01:00 ....24:00
```

Comment: Well lets see ... there's 60 seconds in a minute ....

Comment: Take a look at [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: Expanding on Brian's comment: then you would probably add "30 minutes" worth of time. This will vary by library, but since "30 minutes" is the same as "1800 (30 * 60) seconds" ..

Comment: Keep mind that not all days are 24 hours long. They may be 23, 25, or some other number of hours long.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Possibly a little over kill, but it does all the auto rolling and allows the use of `DateFormat`

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
int startDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
while (cal.get(Calendar.DATE) == startDate) {
    System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
}
```

You can't have `24:00` as it's `00:00`...

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this this code

```
private void displayTimeSlots() {

    String timeValue = "T00:00:4.896+05:30";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    try {
        Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        startCalendar.setTime(sdf.parse(timeValue));

        if (startCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 30) {
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        } else {
            startCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30); // overstep hour and clear minutes
            startCalendar.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
        }

        Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        endCalendar.setTime(startCalendar.getTime());

        // if you want dates for whole next day, uncomment next line
        //endCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        endCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24 - startCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

        endCalendar.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
        endCalendar.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
        endCalendar.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

        SimpleDateFormat slotTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        while (endCalendar.after(startCalendar)) {

            startCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            String Timeslots = slotTime.format(startCalendar.getTime());


            Log.e("DATE", Timeslots);
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // date in wrong format
    }
}
```

Comment: @ArslanShahid FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
myLocalTime.plusMinutes( gapInMinutes )  // Using `java.time.LocalTime` class.
```

## Details

I am answering your Question as written, for a 24-hour day. But beware that days are not always that length. They may be 23, 25, or some other number of hours.

No such thing as `24:00` as that means rolling over to `00:00`. So a duration of 30 minutes means ending at 23:30.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old date-time time classes.

### `LocalTime` & `Duration`

The [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class represents a time-of-day without date and without time zone. This class assumes a generic 24-hour day (unrealistic though that is).

The [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class represents a span-of-time not attached to the timeline.

```
int gapInMinutes =  30 ;  // Define your span-of-time.
int loops = ( (int) Duration.ofHours( 24 ).toMinutes() / gapInMinutes ) ;
List<LocalTime> times = new ArrayList<>( loops ) ;

LocalTime time = LocalTime.MIN ;  // '00:00'
for( int i = 1 ; i <= loops ; i ++ ) {
    times.add( time ) ;
    // Set up next loop.
    time = time.plusMinutes( gapInMinutes ) ;
}

System.out.println( times.size() + " time slots: " ) ;
System.out.println( times ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/6CkeFx).

> 48 time slots:
>
> [00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, 02:00, 02:30, 03:00, 03:30, 04:00, 04:30, 05:00, 05:30, 06:00, 06:30, 07:00, 07:30, 08:00, 08:30, 09:00, 09:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30, 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30, 18:00, 18:30, 19:00, 19:30, 20:00, 20:30, 21:00, 21:30, 22:00, 22:30, 23:00, 23:30]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
instance.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a").parse("00:00:00 AM"));
System.out.println(instance.getTime());
int i=1;
while(i++!=49){
     instance.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
     System.out.println(instance.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Great minds (although I might point out that it goes from 00:00 to 00:00 +1 day ;))...